# Busca valor dentro de url Google

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso buscar e fazer aparecer somente os valores da URL do Google vídeo, buscando um valor especifico. Neste caso eu tenho esse código abaixo, com tudo não esta pegando o valor `0B7fH_c8_hjWVY1pQQVc3dGgxOWs` que fica entre o `/d/` e o `/preview`.

Como posso resolver isso de forma a que o resultado de O valor do item é `0B7fH_c8_hjWVY1pQQVc3dGgxOWs`:

```
<?php // Retorna um valor na posição 2 pegando o dominio do item como base pra retirar o ID
function buscarID ($urlGeral, $dominio) {
preg_match("/^.*($dominio\/)(\d+)-*/", $urlGeral, $valores);
return $valores[2];
}

echo 'O valor do item e '.buscarID('https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7fH_c8_hjWVY1pQQVc3dGgxOWs/preview', "docs.google.com"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar o regex assim:

```
preg_match('file\/d\/(.*?)\/preview', $urlGeral, $valores);
```

Além disso, lembra que usando o `"$variavel"` do PHP, o PHP põe exatamente o que a variável tem para dentro do string. Ou seja, seu Regex como está ficaria assim:

```
^.*(docs.google.com\/)(\d+)-*
```

Mas isso não bate em nada do `$urlGeral`.

Uma ferramenta ótima de testar regex é [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), que te mostra exatamente o que está sendo encontrado.